# Updating all records that have changed since last update

Tags: mongodb

I am working with Mongo for the first time and I am trying to sync data from an API call to a local Mongo collection. Within the collection the data looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5baabbf70456c16b19bfd1e3"),
"id" : "25770a02bd285ca21d428ae4",
"created" : "2016-02-25T03:06:30.814Z",
"is_public" : true,
"kind" : "aspect",
"name" : "Last Open",
"table" : "user",
"tags" : [
    "aspect",
    "predefined",
    "default"
],
"updated" : "2016-09-09T00:59:54.823Z"
}
```

I would like to update any document within the collection whenever the updated time from the API call with that ID is greater than the updated time from the document that matches that ID in the collection.

So far I have a filter that seems to work but trying to use bulkWrite only appends the entire collection to the end. Is there a way to update rather than append? Below is the code I have for filtering and writing.

```
mongoUpsert(myMongoDB.collection("mongosegment"), apiResponse.data, function () {
    db.close();
});

function mongoUpsert(collection, data_array, cb) {

    var ops = data_array.map(function (data) {
        return {
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": {
                    "id": data.id, // or any other filtering mechanism to identify a doc
                    "updated": {
                        "$gt": data.updated
                    }
                },
                "update": {
                    "$set": data
                },
                "upsert": true
            }
        };
    });

    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function (err, r) {});

    return cb(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need { multi : true }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I made a couple of errors. I thought I'd share to help anyone else coming to mongo. First, I had the filter to read `$gt` instead of `$lt`. This means that everything returned false, because the latest query could not return an updated time that was before the stored values. This was an over-site in the way I thought the query worked. Second, I had `upsert: true`, which writes a new document whenever updateOne's filter fails. If updateOne's filter succeeds, then it updates the document. In my case, I forced them all to fail and thus doubled my documents on each run. I also ended up using `replaceOne` as I wanted to replace the whole document if it matched my filter. Here is the final working code for this part:

```
function mongoUpsert(collection, data_array) {
    var ops = data_array.map(function (data) {
        return {
            "replaceOne": {
                "filter": {
                    "id": data.id,
                    "updated": {
                        "$lt": data.updated
                    }
                },
                "replacement": {
                    "$set": data
                },
                "upsert": false
            }
        };
    });

    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function (err, r) {
        insertUniqueDocs(collection, data_array);
    });
}
```